# How to remove the time duration numbers of video from the player?

Tags: html5-video, mediaelement.js

I'm using the mediaelementjs player successfully. With this code:

```
<video id="vid1" poster="/img/test.jpg" preload="none" controls="controls" width="130" height="120" >
<source type="video/mp4" src="http://www...com/video/test1.mp4" />
</video>
```

On the web page the player shows all zeros until the play button is selected and then it shows video length in minutes, and starts counting the video seconds, but only appears upon mousing-over (after it starts). How can I remove these numbers altogether? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove 'current' and 'duration' from line

```
features: [......],
```

when you init new MediaElement instance